# Elementary Installer Stuck on Wifi Selection Screen

Tags: wifi, macbook

I am trying to install Elementary OS on my Macbook Pro 15" early 2013 and the installer freezes on wifi selection system. I can select a Wi-Fi, enter a password or continue without selecting a wifi. The problem starts when i click continue to go to the next step. Nothing happens.

**In short,** even though it recognizes wifi networks, the installer freezes to continue after wifi selection screen.

**Things i have tried:**
- Different USBs,
- Unetbootin and Etcher,
- Try Elementary OS without installing (everything including wifi works but the installer is again stuck)
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 18.10 (they don't recognize wifi drivers so i didn't attempt to install)

[image: Wifi Selection screen on installer]

Comment: Can you post the logs from `/var/log/installer`?

Comment: @trishmapow when i try elementary os without installing and then run the installer; your command on terminal says bash: /var/log/installer: Is a directory

Comment: Yep I mean post the files that are in that directory so we can see what is happening when it crashes.

Comment: There are two files there: 

The debug is: https://textuploader.com/1amuc

Version: ubiquity 18.04.14.8+elementary28~ubuntu5.0.1

Comment: Hmm ok what about /var/log/syslog?

Comment: It is a big file, so i copied the end of the document and one repeating line on top of it: http://txt.do/1amfu